# Align text next to appended form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a form with an appended button. What I need is to align some text to the right of the form so that they're both vertically aligned next to each other.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span4" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wbmLH/

HTML:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="span4" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search">Button</i>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="extraText">Extra Text</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-append, .extraText {
    display:inline-block;
}
```